# Java foreach with lambda which calls method with "outside" variable as argument

Tags: java

Hi I have a code below.

```
int newId =0;
cars.stream()
     .filter(c -> c.getId() == null)
     .forEach(c -> setId(new CarId(newId++));
```

But it cannot be compiled because variable `newId` is not **final**. Is it possible to fix it somehow? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I would rather recommend to use `AtomicInteger` in this case. It would work well also in case of parallel stream processing and is (IMHO) nicer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have unique IDs (rather than just sequential IDs) then you can move the `newId` variable to be a (private?) static member of the `CarID` class.

```
public class CarID {
   protected static int newID = 0;

   private final int id;

   public CarID(){
     this.id = CarID.newID++;
   }
}
```

(Possibly also adding some thread safe behaviour).

Then you can do:

```
cars.stream()
     .filter(c -> c.getId() == null)
     .forEach(c -> setId(new CarId());
```

Comment: I don't like this at all. It's a multithreading problem waiting to happen. Also the id generation is now hardcoded into the class, so later switching to, say, database generated ids is impossible.

Comment: The `c-> methodName` helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend refactoring it to good old for-each-loop:

```
int newId = 0;
for (Car c : cars) {
   if (c.getId() == null) 
        c.setId(new CarId(newId++));
}
```

Reasons:

- The stream's result is not deterministic: The ids you set may have a random order, which can differ among several executions (but I think you can live with that).
- Side-effects are discouraged when using streams.
- While the use of `AtomicInteger` is  fine (but slow) regarding threads, other solutions my result in problems when the stream is going to be parallel for some reasons.